# How to use FolderListModel

Tags: qml, qtquick2

I create a QtQuick app and replace the main.qml with the code below. I try to show all files and dirs in my home path in a Mac OS X system. But nothing shows up. How can I figure out what I did wrong?

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 2.1

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    title: "Test"
    width: 200
    height: 400

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent

        FolderListModel {
            id: folderModel
            showDirs: true
            showDirsFirst: true
            rootFolder: "file:///Users/enderson"
            nameFilters: ["*.*"]
        }

        Component {
            id: fileDelegate
            Text { text: fileName }
        }

        model: folderModel
        delegate: fileDelegate
    }
}
```

b.t.w.:
Qt5.5
and .pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = app

QT += qml quick widgets

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    UiBridge.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

LIBS += -framework CoreFoundation -framework Foundation

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
include(deployment.pri)
```

Comment: try to replace `rootFolder: "file:///Users/enderson"` with `folder: "/Users/enderson"`

Comment: @folibis Thanks, it works. However, this confused me a little 'cause the qt online document seems that folder param is for reading current explored dir. After all, thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the problem. Using rootFolder is wrong. Use 'folder' property like below

```
folder: "file:///Users/enderson"
```