# Can i replace QFileSystemModel+QSortFilterProxyModel+QTreeView with QtQuick?

Tags: python, qml, qtquick2, pyside2

I haven't used QML/QtQuick, but I've heard it's simpler.

I want to build a local file management system, which needs QFileSystemModel + QSortFilterProxyModel + QTreeView.

My question is: can i use QML/QtQuick to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about simpler, especially in this case. I suppose it depends on the UI feature set you're looking for. Of course almost anything *can* be done if you really want/need to, but...

The biggest (perhaps) obstacle from what you mention is that there isn't really a supported Tree View component. There's the old Controls 1 [TreeView](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls-treeview.html), but this is deprecated (ironically it shows an example of a file browser tree, but this is a [red herring](https://forum.qt.io/topic/94552/qml-folderlistmodel-treeview-tree-view)). It's also based on a ton of QML/JS code which is just slow. There's no suitable [replacement](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-differences.html#type-comparison-table) in Controls 2 that I know of.

Then there's the lack of a simple `QSortFilterProxyModel` equivalent. I guess we're supposed to use [`DelegateModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-delegatemodel.html) for this sort of thing, but it's awkward at best. Eg. check out [this example](https://martin.rpdev.net/2019/01/15/using-delegatemodel-in-qml-for-sorting-and-filtering.html). Now it's not actually that hard to make a `QSortFilterProxyModel` subclass which plays nice with QML, and there are some published versions of such out there (eg. [this](https://github.com/oKcerG/SortFilterProxyModel) but I have not personally tried it), but it's a surprising lack in the base QML components IMHO. One can also create/configure a `QSortFilterProxyModel` in C++ and expose it to QML as a context property (or similar), but then of course it needs to be manipulated from C++ side as well (eg. here's a rather verbose [example](http://imaginativethinking.ca/use-qt-qsortfilterproxymodel/) of doing it that way).

And finally `QFileSystemModel` is not really exposed to QtQuick either. There's the Labs' version of [FolderListModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-folderlistmodel-folderlistmodel.html) which is sort-of close (but note especially that it's a list model, not a tree model). You could also expose a `QFileSystemModel` from C++ (as a context property for example), but this may not be so straight-forward either (eg. see this [answerless question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38169880/using-qfilesystemmodel-with-listview)).

So, YMMV. If one needs a "universal" UI (desktop/mobile/etc) then frankly HTML/CSS/JS might be a better option (with a Qt C++ back end, of course ;-). Personally I found QML frustrating for writing desktop-like apps because a lot of functionality is missing in the available QML components and subclassing in C++ is almost impossible because most of the "good stuff" is all private API.